# How to get the number of youtube playlist videos with php

Tags: php, youtube-api, gdata

As you know, the maximum number of videos to retrieve from a YouTube playlist is 50, i need to retrieve more, so i need to know how much videos in a playlist and then loop a number of times to get them all 50 by 50.

How can i do this using YouTube PHP API, without crawling playlist page.

Comment: RTFM => https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list. it mentions things like `totalResults` vs `resultsPerPage`, and includes words like `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken`. i would start there.

Answer (score 1):

If your response from youtube includes a `nextPageToken` in the body then you need to resend the exact same request but with the additional parameter `"pageToken": {VALUE FROM nextPageToken in response}` to get the next page of results.  Keep doing this until there isn't a `nextPageToken` in the response body.